# Getting a list of custom posts by author

Tags: custom-post-types, author

I'm trying to have a page where a user can view all of the custom post types after they click on an author from a previous page, but I'm having no luck with anything I can find in the built-in PHP functions with Wordpress.

Is this some easy to query? I haven't found much online about it.

Comment: Is it one specific post type, or do you mean "anything that isn't a WordPress core type"?

Comment: It's just one specific custom post type.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should work:

```
// Assuming you've got $author_id set
// and your post type is called 'your_post_type'
$args = array(
    'author' => $author_id,
    'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
);
$author_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $author_posts->have_posts() ) {
    while( $author_posts->have_posts() ) { 
        $author_posts->the_post();
        // title, content, etc
        $author_posts->the_title();
        $author_posts->the_content();
        // you should have access to any of the tags you normally
        // can use in The Loop
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

#### Reference

[`WP_Query` class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

### Using an Author Template file

You can do this inside an Author Template:

#### `author.php`-- this file belongs in your theme's directory

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content" class="narrowcolumn">

<!-- This sets the $curauth variable -->

<?php
    $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? 
        get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : 
        get_userdata(intval($author));
?>

<h2>About: <?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?></h2>
<dl>
    <dt>Website</dt>
    <dd><a href="<?php echo $curauth->user_url; ?>"><?php echo $curauth->user_url; ?></a></dd>
    <dt>Profile</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $curauth->user_description; ?></dd>
</dl>

<h2>Posts by <?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?>:</h2>

<ul>
<!-- The Loop -->
<?php

// Assuming your post type is called 'your_post_type'
$args = array(
    'author' => $curauth->ID,
    'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
);
$author_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $author_posts->have_posts() ) {
    while( $author_posts->have_posts() ) {
        $author_posts->the_post();
        // title, content, etc
        the_title();
        the_content();
        // you should have access to any of the tags you normally
        // can use in The Loop
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>

<!-- End Loop -->

</ul>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This `author.php` template code is shamelessly cribbed from [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates#Sample_Template_File), and should probably be considered a starting point, not an end product.

Comment: I know I'll get some flack for this.. but I'm trying to do this with "Allow PHP in Post and Pages" and it seems to be having a problem with the if statement. I can't figure out why, but it just gives up trying to do anything as soon as it gets to that point.

Comment: The code I posted is mean to be added to your `functions.php` file or a plugin.  I've got no experience using the Allow PHP in Posts and Pages plugin(?).

Comment: How would I add it to the functions.php? I'm not super great with PHP. I'm guessing I have to dump it in a function, but I'm not sure how to do the add_action stuff or how to call it from a page.

Comment: I've updated my response.

Comment: Hi there, late response, but I am trying your way for a user's posts in a CPT (events), but unfortunately, end up with a 500 server error on a user's page that actually has posted something - users without posts (i.e. empty query) work just fine. Can you have a look? See a paste of my author template file (overlook the crap with custom fields :) ) here: http://pastebin.com/NLNSYC0c . Thanks already!

Comment: Update: I got it sorted, with my limited knowledge of PHP. You actually have to replace `$author_posts->the_title();` with the standard get_the_title() etc., and it works flawlessly (see http://pastebin.com/1FHFGFQs). Thanks for bringing me on the right track though (maybe you could update your solution above).

Comment: I've updated the code. If `get_the_title()` works, then `the_title()` & `the_content()` should as well. (Turns out I'm doing something quite similar in a site I set up some time ago.)

Comment: That first bit works great.  Simply used `get_the_author_meta('ID');` to set the `$author_id`.

Comment: You forgot the closing parenthesis on the while statement:

`while( $author_posts->have_posts()) {`

Comment: So I did. Good catch. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to add your custom post type to your author.php template

In your functions.php, add the following code. This will add your custom post type to the main query so that it will appear on your author page

```
function wpse107459_add_cpt_author( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_author() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse107459_add_cpt_author' );
```

With this, there are no need to make any changes to your template files :-)

Comment: Hi @PieterGoosen  This is almost perfect for what i need, but I would like to only show the CPT.  On the $query->set line i could just remove 'post', but this will cause issues on the main blog.  Do you know how i would set it so the code only applies to custom post types?  In pseudo code it would be: if (post-type('cpt-name') { // do the code } but I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just solved my issue after trying 10 different other methods.